# Using IGameComponent and related interfaces in MonoGame

Tags: xna, monogame, porting

I am trying to port a XNA project to MonoGame which involves a DLL game library that I created. This library uses the IGameComponent, IUpdateable and IDrawable interfaces to load one of my library classes as a GameComponent.

The compiler gives errors related to these interfaces, saying, for example: *The type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.IUpdateable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game'...*

This would require me to add Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game to my reference list, which defeats the point of porting to MonoGame. Is there any way these interfaces can be made compatible with MonoGame

Comment: Monogame has it's own IUpdateable.  Check you .dll and fix IT'S reference to point to Monogame's framework.

Comment: So my library project should have another build, to refer to MonoGame?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to recompile your DLL game library after changing all the XNA references to  MonoGame references.

MonoGame redefines the interfaces under the same namespace but in a different assembly. It makes things easier to port once you understand whats going on, but can make errors like this slightly confusing.